# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Tags: java, email

I am sending e email using an SMTP error . I am getting Authentication unsuccessful. The username and password are correct. Am I doing something wrong.

The error logs are

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class EmailSender{

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String to = "ssss@xxx.om";            // sender email
        String from = "dddd@xxx.com";       // receiver email
        String host = "dkdkdd.xxx.com";                   // mail server host

        String login="dkkdkd";
        String pass="dkkdkd";
       Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.user", login);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtps.ssl.enable", "true");
       // properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties); // default session

        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);        // email message
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));                    // setting header fields
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("Test Mail from Java Program"); // subject line

            // actual mail body
            message.setText("You can send mail from Java program by using");

            // Send message
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, login, pass);
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Email Sent successfully....");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The error is

DEBUG SMTP: AUTH NTLM failed
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:826)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:761)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:685)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

Answer (score 16):

Had the same issue. It's an MS Exchange error that you receive. You are probably not allowed to use your email to send an email via a relay. The administrator of the Exchange server needs to give the rights to do that.

It has nothing to do with a configuration problem on the Java side.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem in how you do the session part...

try doing this:

```
private Properties emailPorperties;
```

...
...

```
    emailPorperties = new Properties();
    emailPorperties.put("mail.smtp.host", "your host");
    emailPorperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "your port");
    emailPorperties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    emailPorperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    emailPorperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "your port");
    emailPorperties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    emailSession = Session.getInstance(emailPorperties, new Authenticator() {

            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                System.out.println("Authenticating");
                return new PasswordAuthentication(USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
            }

        });
```

Comment: I already tried this, and I am getting same error ie                                    Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Comment: set the auth to true again...@MukeshKumar and add  
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your Prompt reply.  I added what you mentioned . I am getting error 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;  nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1907)at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:666)

Comment: I don't have any  SSL certificate of the mail server to be set and the mail server doesn't require too

Comment: Wich version of mail jar are you using? @MukeshKumar

Comment: javax.mail-api-1.4.7.jar

Comment: I've tried with mail-1.4.5 + javax-mail-1.3.3.01 and it works... see edited answer... @MukeshKumar

Comment: Thanks for your time.Can you share your code. I am getting confused.

Comment: I tried what u Instructed but still same Issue.                                 Authenticating
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

Hello i've got the same issue in the past.
So to solve it i have to connect on the webmail of my outlook or exchage and i noticed that these connexions were stopped by the server so inside i confirm that these transactions was mine.
So u have also to do it usually every 2 month in my case.

The problem is not in the code. The problem occurs because something is wrong with the configuration of the mailboxes I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue resolve by enabling IMAP of the sender email account in Exchange Control Panel (ECP) of outlook mail admin.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Microsoft admin account and **turn off the multi-factor authentication**.

By default it is enabled. Once you disable the multi-factor authentication then it works fine for me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and in my case, the issue was 'outlook password got expired'.
As I had it logged in default I did not have any issue while logging in to my mail.

I tried logging in to incognito mode and see if my logging asked for an additional layer for logging like multi-factor auth, And when logged in from the incognito tab it asked to change the password with a popup stating 'password got expired'.

I then updated the new password and it started to work fine !!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31697227)