# javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Cannot send mail

Tags: java, email, authentication

I'm having trouble with error

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3

Authentication when trying to send an email. I've tried using two different email accounts. One using **Office365 server** details and the other using **Gmail server** details.

In both cases I get the same error. My code is below. Outside of my code the email addresses can send and receive email successfully without issue. This is my email class as it is the part that isn't working. All other aspects of my program work. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

```
    public class SPUREMAIL{

//CONSTANTS - Things that will never change
private static final String HOST = "smtp.office365.com";
private static final String PORT = "587";
private static final String SENDER = "EMAIL";
private static final String PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";
private static final String SUBJECT = "Spur Design has shared a file with you";
private static final String MESSAGE = "This email message was sent from an unmonitored address. Please contact your Spur Design representative for any questions or concerns";

//this item will change, its the direct link to the file
private String URLToFile;
private String recipient;

public SPUREMAIL(String URLToFile, String recipient){
    this.URLToFile = URLToFile;
    this.recipient = recipient;
}

//Properties for email
private Properties getProperties(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", HOST);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", PORT);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.user", SENDER);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.password", PASSWORD);
    return properties;
}


//Creating an email session so I can authenticate to server
Session session = Session.getInstance(getProperties(), new javax.mail.Authenticator(){ 
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
        return new PasswordAuthentication(SENDER, PASSWORD);
    }
});

public void sendMail(){//This will actually attempt to send the email successfully
    try{
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(SENDER));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
        message.setSubject(SUBJECT);
        message.setText(MESSAGE);
        Transport.getTransport("smtp");
        Transport.connect(HOST, SENDER, PASSWORD, pass);
        Transport.sendMessage(MESSAGE, message.getAllRecipients());
    }
    catch(MessagingException e){
        System.out.println("send failed, exception: " + e);
    }
    System.out.println("Sent!!!!");
}
```

}

Comment: Edit: I just obesrved the line `Transport.connect(HOST, SENDER, passW, pass);` should be `Transport.connect(HOST, SENDER, PASSWORD, pass);` but even after changing the error still occurs.

Comment: There's no way that code even compiles; you're trying to call Transport instance methods as if they were static methods.  Please post the code you're actually using.  See the JavaMail FAQ for [common JavaMail mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), and post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) if it's still not working.  And make sure that SENDER is the user name you use to login with, which may be different than the email From address in your messages.

Comment: Bill, I respect your answer and apprecate your help. Prior to posting the code I double/triple/quadruple checked and it compiles absolutely fine.

Comment: You’re wrong, check again.  javax.mail.Transport  does not have a getTransport method.  Session does, but if you’re calling it you’ll want to save the result, which you are not.  There is no “pass” variable in your code, and there is no connect method that takes 4 strings.  The sendMessage method takes a Message object, not a String.  Do I need to go on?

Comment: Bill, I digress and apologize if I came off as rude,. I went in and manually compiled the email class and started getting compiler errors, all the ones you referenced. After addressing the errors, successfully compiling the email class, and then compiling the rest of my project everything works splendidly. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue with my code was two-fold. One, the email class was not being compiled when I compiled the entirety of my project. This was causing my Transport calls to go unchecked. Changed the Transport calls to the bloc below and after manually compiling email class successfully I was able to send emails perfectly fine. All credit goes to Bill Shannon for pointing me in the right direction.

```
public void sendMail(){//This will actually attempt to send the email successfully
        try{
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(SENDER));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
            message.setSubject(SUBJECT);
            message.setText(MESSAGE);
            Transport.send(message, message.getAllRecipients());
        }
        catch(MessagingException e){
            System.out.println("send failed, exception: " + e);
        }
        System.out.println("Sent!!!!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestion which you can try and check if they work for you.

1. If you are trying outlook, I am assuming you are trying to connect your internal organization email servers. Try with port 25 and check if setting mail.smtp.starttls.enable to false make a difference.
2. I don't think you need to use username and password. You can remove it in case of outlook. You will need that in case of gmail.
3. You might want white-list your ip address by the firewall team. They have to allow connection from your machine.
4. Try installing a local email server, I have used papercut and it works like a charm.
5. Before sending your email using gmail you have to allow non secure apps to access gmail you can do this by going to your gmail settings. 
   [image]

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked this link -
[javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243450/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-535-5-7-3-authentication-unsuccessful)

It says it could the mail server configuration issue for your organization where your email id is not allowed to send mail via code. May be your mail server administrator can help here.

Also, this link - https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/unable-to-send-email-due-to-javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-error-message-151519398.html , says the cause could be the mail server configured incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a pretty change will make a huge response, this case is also like that. You have to give full mail address at username. Sender's mail id's username should be with @domain.com

username : `******_****@domain.com`