# Sending mails with JavaMailSender throws AuthenticationFailedException

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm using JavaMailSender to send emails, when I use the gmail smtp all seems to work fine, but when I tried to use our internal smtp mail server I got this error:

> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.1 Authentication
>   failed

After some googling, I found in this thread : [javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243450/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-535-5-7-3-authentication-unsuccessful) that I'm probably not allowed to use my email to send an email via a relay. The administrator of the Exchange server needs to give the rights to do that.

I contacted the administrator and he told me that they cannot allow anonymous relay on the Exchange server due to security issues, and he asked me is there any other way to use Java for sending emails without using an anonymous relay.

Any one knows any solution for this ?

## Update:

This is the cofiguration I'm using :

```
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.host=smtp.secret.fr
spring.mail.username=secret@secret.com
spring.mail.password=secret
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

## Update 2:

This is the full stack trace :

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.6.2
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.secret.fr", port 587, isSSL false
220 GARM-102R004 Friday, February 1, 2019
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.secret.fr", port: 587
EHLO PC100043.secret.fr
250-OVH SMTP PROXY Hello
250-SIZE 104857600
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
250-STARTTLS
250 8BITMIME
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "104857600"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH=LOGIN", arg "PLAIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO PC100043.secret.fr
250-OVH SMTP PROXY Hello
250-SIZE 104857600
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
250 8BITMIME
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "104857600"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH=LOGIN", arg "PLAIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=smtp.secret.fr, user=secret@secret.fr, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
```

Comment: The error indicates you are authenticating, but that you are using the wrong credentials. Ask your admin what authentication is supported and which credentials you should use. If you can't get it to work, make sure to at least post a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks ,but for the credentials I'm sure that they are not wrong, as I use the same when configuring a new account in MS Outlook, and for `what authentication is supported` I didn't understand what you mean. I have updated my question by providing the configuration I'm using.

Comment: In this case you should ask your admin why authentication is failing (eg maybe you need to use `secret` as the username instead of `secret@secret.com`, or something else entirely).

Comment: You probably need to use your Windows user name instead of your email address to authenticate.