# AuthenticationFailedException in sending email from java code

Tags: java, email, outlook, mime

I am trying to write a small java program that can send email from my corporate outlook account. I am planning to run this java program on my office machine only. Below is my program:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(my_email_id, my_password);
            }
          });
        
        MimeMessage mime = new MimeMessage(session);
        
        try {
            mime.setSender(new InternetAddress(emailid));
            mime.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(emailid));
            mime.setSubject("Test");
            mime.setText("Testing");
            Transport.send(mime);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am getting below error :

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [BM1PR01CA0166.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]
```

I have tried removing the socketFactory properties as well, but no luck. Can anyone help me out with this one? I am guessing it might have something to do with proxy or any other security on my office machine, but I am not able to figure out what it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243450/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-535-5-7-3-authentication-unsuccessful)

Comment: @RubioRic It says "The administrator of the Exchange server needs to give the rights to send an email via a relay". Is there any way around that?

Comment: I'm no expert in MS Exchange, sorry. I just found that pretty similar question.

Comment: If you want hack work around in the mean time you could use another mail client like google to send the email from your program to your self at your work email, then setup a rule in outlook to forward the message from your work email whenever it comes from that account to the proper recipients.

Comment: @DaveThomas This workaround will work but it will show that the mail is forwarded, I don't want that.