# Why I got authentication failed exception when sending emails using spring boot app deployed on AWS EC2?

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, remote-server, smtpclient

when deploying my jar file on a remote server like AWS EC2 and using it to send emails over smtp connection i got :

Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [MN2PR01CA0051.prod.exchangelabs.com]

But it is working proberly when running this app on my local machine,

Is remote servers or there is a configurations must be added ?

Comment: Hi & Welcome! Or: You have missing configuration on your remote machine, or: (In your SMTP server) there is a missing "permission" to send/authenticate from "remote" (but from "local"...however)(?)

Comment: Hi, I confirmed all configs on the remote machine firewall configured properly, but still there is exception,
Is it possible to send emails using  outlook smtp on amazon instance or we have to use amazon SES to send emails

Comment: Best: ask your SMTP admin!:) ... [Possible dup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33243450/592355)(no accepted answer;(