# exception javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Tags: java, email, smtp

I copied code for sending mails with javax.mail from an older project to my new project. The code worked in the old project for an other customizer.

```
       final Properties props = new Properties();
       props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.mycompany.net");
       props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", "10000");
       props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
       props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
       props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
       props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
       props.put("mail.debug", "true");

final class MailAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
                       @Override
                       public javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                             return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
                       }
                 }

                 final Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new MailAuthenticator()); 

                 final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                 msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
                 msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
                 msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
                 msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(replyMail, replyId));
                 msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(replyMail, false));
                 msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
                 msg.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
                 msg.setSentDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate));
                 toEmails = toEmails.replace(";", ",");
                 msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmails, false));

                 Transport.send(msg);
```

But now I get an AuthenticationFailedException

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
```

I use javax.mail version 1.5.0. I tried also version 1.6.2 with the same error.

Here is the log file:

```
DEBUG: Jakarta Mail version 1.6.4.payara-p1
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=mail.mycompany.net, user=ann, password=<null>
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.mycompany.net", port 587, isSSL false
220 SMUCMP04A.europe.mycompany.corp Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 15 Feb 2023 15:23:51 +0100
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "mail.mycompany.net", port: 587
EHLO SWE-mycompany-WS16-09.localdomain
250-SMUCMP04A.europe.mycompany.corp Hello [10.30.85.214]
250-SIZE 20971520
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "20971520"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "GSSAPI NTLM"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
EHLO SWE-mycompany-WS16-09.localdomain
250-SMUCMP04A.europe.mycompany.corp Hello [10.30.85.214]
250-SIZE 20971520
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM LOGIN
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "20971520"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "GSSAPI NTLM LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=mail.mycompany.net, user=myuser@europe.mycompany.corp, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
```

Does anyone have an idea to solve the problem?

Thank you Ann

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243450/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-535-5-7-3-authentication-unsuccessful)

Comment: From the logs it seems the remote server hasn't rejected using the 'LOGIN' mechanism. Sure the credentials are correct? Othrwise might need to run it in a debugger to see deeper details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked my customizer for the user/password combination three times.
And now I asked a fourth time and I get an other password.
With the **new password** I can send mails with my implementation.

Sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you all for the help.

Many greetings Ann

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).