# Getting error: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Tags: spring-boot, smtp

I am Office365 for the email and SMTP auth is enable on my account. But getting Authentication unsuccessful exception.

```
 @Bean
  public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
    mailSender.setHost("smtp.office365.com");
    mailSender.setPort(587);
    mailSender.setUsername("**"); //app generated username and password from outlook
    mailSender.setPassword("*****");
    mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);
    return mailSender;
  }
```

What is wrong in the above configuration? SMTP is enabled on my account. And for the user name and password, I am using app generated username by outlook app generate.

Comment: Possibly the same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243450/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-535-5-7-3-authentication-unsuccessful